# Finding/Mounting USB Device in Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: mount, osx, usb

I have a UPS device which comes with monitoring software but it appears to not find the connected device. I can hard code the `/dev` location into the config file but the problem is I can't find or establish how to link the device itself to this type of assignment.

System Profiler provides the following which I am sure is the correct device:

```
USB Bus:

  Host Controller Location: Built-in USB
  Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBOHCI
  PCI Device ID: 0x7ff200000aa5 
  PCI Revision ID: 0x7ff2000000b1 
  PCI Vendor ID: 0x7ff2000010de 
  Bus Number: 0x04 

    Composite Device:

      Vendor ID: 0x0001  (Kavi-EVAL)
      Version: 1.00
      Speed: Up to 1.5 Mb/sec
      Location ID: 0x04300000 / 3
      Current Available (mA): 500
      Current Required (mA): 100
```

But I simply have no idea (mount?) how to establish the existing, or create the correct mount point for inclusion into the application's cfg file. This is the line extracted from the cfg file:

```
UPS Comport           ( /dev/xxttyxx    )  : [HID/MEC0002]
```

When I look in the `/dev` folder there is no HID/anything or anything that looks to come close to the device info returned by the profiler.

Can anyone explain how I bind the USB device in the system profiler to an assignment I can use in the configuration?

Comment: What is the make and model number of the UPS device?

Comment: @Richard, did you ever get a resolution to this?